# Prism view available after navigate from

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using prism in a wpf application using the latest stable release of 6.2.0

I have setup prism to use the `IRegionMemberLifetime` interface on a view model and have set the `KeepAlive` property to return false. In the view model, when it is create I register to an `IEventAggregator` event using the following code.

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<NewLayerSetEnabledEvent>().Subscribe(NewLayersetEnabledAction);
```

The issue that I am having is that after I have navigated from the view, the view model still exists and when I publish the event this other view is also being called. Is there a way to force the view to be disposed of by GC after it is navigated from or do I need to unsubscribe from the events when the `OnNavigatedFrom` event is called.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing you have to always keep in mind about the Garbage Collector in the .Net CLR, is the fact that you (normally) don't know when exactly it runs. (You could, of course, force the Garbage Collector to run using the `GC.Collect()` method etc, but this is rather an exception and shouldn't be overused - see [this srticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection)).

So keeping that in mind, you can never be sure, when your view will be GC'ed. Generally speaking, it could still be alive for some time and even survive till the application shut down (see [Generation 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#generations)).

If you want to make sure that your closed view's view-model doesn't actively react to the events raised by the `EventAggregator` anymore, you have to unsubscribe from all events just after the view removal.